# Why do I see my excluded folders in PHPStorm 8?

Tags: phpstorm

I just upgraded from PHPStorm 7 to PHPStorm 8, and all of a sudden my excluded directories became visible again. I excluded them not only because I don't want to have them searched or inspected, but also because I just don't need to see them - at all.

**PHPStorm 7.1:**

[image: before update]

**PHPStorm 8.0:**

[image: after update]

How do I remove the red-marked directories from my project view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -- that the change that was introduced in v8. Its purpose is to have these folders still participating in VCS operations and alike -- see [IDEA-23537](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-23537).

To hide such folders from Project View you just need to uncheck `Show Excluded Folders` from Project View panel options (right click on panel title or via menu under "cog" icon).

Comment: Ha! I missed that option. I did search for "excluded" in Preferences but didn't find anything. That's great, thanks.